# Finding friends of a user

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table of user with differents fields : id, firstname, name.
I have a table called friend with differents fields : invite_id, friend_sender (id of a user), friend_receiver (id of a user), validity (boolean).

I'm filling the friend table with

```
1, 1, 2, 0;
2, 3, 1, 1;
3, 1, 5, 1;
```

Let's imagine I'm user 1, and I want to find all my friends. I can be the one who sent the friend invitation (sender), or the one who received it (receiver). When the receiver accept the invitation, the validity of the relation is set to 1. So for example, I'm not friend with user 2 because he didn't accepted.

The result I should get from doing the query with user 1 should be :

```
3, firstnameofuser3, nameofuser3
5, firstnameofuser3, nameofuser3
```

I tried some SQL things, with double JOIN, renaming table to avoid the "double same table" problems etc ... but I couldn't figure it out.

I've found some post about it, but for more complex things, like here :
[Finding mutual friend sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096713/finding-mutual-friend-sql)

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I'm using MySQL, alright gonna edit my post to make it understandable with no image !

Comment: Because you're newbie, if you want you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
WHERE u.id IN (
    SELECT f.friend_sender
    FROM friend f
    WHERE f.friend_receiver = 2 -- My fixed ID about Jin Jey
    UNION 
    SELECT f.friend_receiver
    FROM friend f
    WHERE f.friend_sender = 2 AND f.validity = 1)
```

I used UNION because you can query two sets of data and merge it.

I fixed ID (2) because in your request you want to know all friends about Jin Jey

Comment: Thank you ! It worked perfectly.
I just added  AND f.invitation = 1 before your comment so that it also consider validity for this sub query !

Answer (score 2):

I know there are already answers, but mine is unique AND I have a fiddle! ;)

```
SELECT
id,
firstname,
name
FROM
user
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN friend_sender = 1 THEN friend_receiver ELSE friend_sender END
  FROM friend
  WHERE
  (friend_sender = 1 OR friend_receiver = 1)
  AND
  validity = 1
)
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8f55a/1

Comment: Thank you trex005. It seems you and Joe did something similar, except you are using CASE instead of UNION. Thank you again a lot for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

```
select 
    id,
    firstname, 
    name
from
    user inner join friend
    on
        (friend_sender=1 or friend_receiver=1 )and validity=1
        and 
    user.id=
    (case 
        when friend_sender=1 then friend_receiver
        else friend_sender
    end)
```

<kbd>**[demo link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/605e5b/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you DhruvJoshi. I understood your query I think. I didn't knew you could use INNER JOIN differently than "Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field2" !
Thank you again a lot for your answer.

Comment: Alright I upvoted your post like all the others. Hope it helps you !